# Using PCA algorithm for adjusting data

Tags: matlab, pca

Hello I used MATLAB for doing PCA with the following code (I have 13 attributes) actually I have a problem when I run the program (RBF network) so I used PCA to adjust data,Can I use this method? If yes, should I use matrix als instead of my real data?

```
% PCA1: Perform PCA using covariance.

% data - MxN matrix of input data

% (M dimensions, N trials)

% signals - MxN matrix of projected data

% PC - each column is a PC

% V - Mx1 matrix of variances

[M,N] = size(data);

% subtract off the mean for each dimension

mn = mean(data,2);

data = data - repmat(mn,1,N);

% calculate the covariance matrix

covariance = 1 / (N-1) * data * data’;

% find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues

[PC, V] = eig(covariance);

% extract diagonal of matrix as vector

V = diag(V);

% sort the variances in decreasing order

[junk, rindices] = sort(-1*V);

V = V(rindices);

PC = PC(:,rindices);

% project the original data set

sign

als = PC’ * data;
```

Thanks

Comment: consider properly formatting the code in your question, please

Comment: Thanks please help me if you know about this?

Comment: I'm not clear what your question is. What do you mean by "signal matrix"?

Comment: I mean the final output that appears in workspace as a signals?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, matrix `als` is the new transformed data set. In order to control the dimensionality of this new data, you can modify PC by taking most important `k` vectors;

```
PC = PC(:,1:k);
```

In order the find the transformed equivalent of a new sample `X` (N by 1) you can write:

```
X_transformed = PC’ * X;
```

Comment: Thanks, I have a problem when I run the program (RBF network) so I used PCA to adjust data,Can I use this method? If yes, should I use matrix als instead of my real data?